# Adding User Registartion to Database Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm following a tutorial to add new users to my database via a html form and flask. I'm able to run the code using the html template with: localhost/5000

But if I enter the data that should be add to the database I get the following error:

**The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

with this url: **http://localhost:5000/sign_in?stage=login**

Python code:

```
@app.route("/")

def showForm():
# show our html form to the user
t_message = "Python and Postgres Registration Application"
return render_template("register.html", message = t_message)
@app.route("/register", methods=["POST","GET"])
def register():
# get user input from the html form
t_email = request.form.get("t_email", "")
t_password = request.form.get("t_password", "")

# check for blanks
if t_email == "":
    t_message = "Please fill in your email address"
    return render_template("register.html", message = t_message)

if t_password == "":
    t_message = "Please fill in your password"
    return render_template("register.html", message = t_message)

# hash the password they entered
t_hashed = hashlib.sha256(t_password.encode())
t_password = t_hashed.hexdigest()

# database insert
t_host = "localhost"
t_port = "5432"
t_dbname = "register_dc"
t_user = "postgres"
t_pw = "=5.k7wT=!D"
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=t_host, port=t_port, dbname=t_dbname, user=t_user, password=t_pw)
db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

# We take the time to build our SQL query string so that
#   (a) we can easily & quickly read it
#   (b) we can easily & quickly edit or add/remote lines
#   The more complex the query, the greater the benefits
s = "INSERT INTO public.users "
s += "("
s += "  t_email"
s += ", t_password"
s += ") VALUES ("
s += " '" + t_email + "'"
s += ",'" + t_password + "'"
s += ")"

db_cursor.execute(s)
try:
    db_conn.commit()
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    t_message = "Database error: " + e + "/n SQL: " + s
    return render_template("register.html", message = t_message)

t_message = "Your user account has been added."
return render_template("register.html", message = t_message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML code:

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    
   function checkform (form)
   {
       /* isEmpty() returns true and alerts the user if they left a field empty */
       function isEmpty (fixwhat, s_called)
       {
           if (fixwhat=="")
           {
           alert("Please enter " + s_called);
           return true;
           } else {
           return false;
           }
       }

       /* charCheck() returns false and alerts the user if they used any non-alphanumeric characters */
       function charCheck(fixwhat)
       {
           var validchars = '@-_.0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
           if(isValid(fixwhat,validchars))
           {
               return true;
           } else {
               alert("Please use only letters or numbers in this field");
               return false;
           }
       }

       /* isValid is used by the charCheck() function to look through each 'validchars' one at a time */
       function isValid(string,validchars)
       {
           for (var i=0; i< string.length; i++)
           {
           if (validchars.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) === -1) {return false;}
           }
           return true;
       }

       // Check for empty fields
       if (is_empty (form.t_email.value,"your email address")) { form.t_email.focus();  return false;}
      
       if (is_empty (form.t_password.value,"your password")) { form.t_password.focus();  return false;}

       //check for weird chars
       if (charCheck(form.t_email.value)===false) {form.t_email.focus(); return false;}
      
       if (charCheck(form.t_password.value)===false) {form.t_password.focus(); return false;}

       return true ;
   }
   
    </script>

   <div class='container'>


<form id='frmSignIn' name='frmSignIn' action='/sign_in?stage=login' method='post' onsubmit='return checkform(this);'>

<div class="form-row">
  <label for="Email">Email address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="t_email" name="t_email">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label for="Email">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="t_password" name="t_password">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <input type="submit" id="btn_submit_sign_in" value='Sign In'>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the route `/sign_in` in your browser (and in your template), but you declared your route as `/register`, thus a 404 is returned.